# How to save a GeoJSON layer with the select option for the items in a field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, layers, definition-query

I have a GeoJSON layers with many items. If you open the attribute table you can select an option in one field clicking over the field and the choosing one of the displayed options. The problem is that  I don't know how to save the GeoJSON  layer with the options that I chose. I want to save the options chosen so when I open the layer again, the chosen options will be the selected ones by default.

Comment: Is the GeoJSON local or provided through some service?

Comment: GeoJSON is a format for encoding a variety of geographic data structures.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I don't quite understand what you mean. 

Geojson layer - yep
Attribute table - So assume Right Click > Open Attribute Table
Field display options - not sure what you mean here? Do you mean the column width? Or the sorting?